# Форма не проходит проверку на пустоту

Tags: php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Расчет акциза</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn">
    </form>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btn"])){
    $numbers = $_POST["numbers"];
    if((empty($numbers))){
      echo "Неверные данные!";
    }else{
      foreach($numbers as $numKey => $number){
        echo $number."<br/>";
      }
    }
}
?>
```

При отправке пустой формы, не выводиться ошибка.

Comment: Обработка ошибок должна быть до рендеринга страницы и выводится во время рендеринга.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Вы имеете ввиду, пхп поставить выше хтмл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Незаполененная форма отправит вовсе не пустой массив, а массив с пустыми значениями

```
['','','','','']
```

Можно выбросить такие пустые значения из массива до проверки, и тогда все сработает

```
if((empty(array_filter($numbers)))){
```

---

Обратите внимание на замечание @teran: если у вас разрешены к вводу все 0, то проверка через array_filter вырежет такие зачения. Надо его немного усложнить, например

```
if((empty(array_filter($numbers, function ($x) { return $x !== ""; })))){
```

Comment: массив с одними `"0"`будет отфильтрован в пустой

Comment: @splash58 это сработало. Спасибо!